# * in print function in python

Tags: python, string, printing, stdout

```
text = 'PYTHON'
for index in range(len(text)):
    print(*text[:index + 1])
```

The * in the *print* function is producing a space between the characters on *sys.stdout*. Can someone please tell me what is it called and what does it actually do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The print of * for a text is equal as printing `print(text[0], text[1], ..., text[n])` and this is printing each part with a space between.
you can do

```
text = 'PYTHON'
for index in range(len(text))
    print("".join(list(text)[:index + 1]))
```

or

```
text = 'PYTHON'
for index in range(len(text))
    print(*text[:index + 1], sep='')
```

that will print each part without space in between.
Output

```
P
PY
PYT
PYTH
PYTHO
PYTHON
```

Comment: Thanks — Brilliantly explained!!

Comment: Started by udemy course and then alot of self learning online and for the last 4 years this is my profession

Comment: Thanks — Is there a resource that explains python in detail (like what exactly happens in memory when dictionaries are created and other things)?

Comment: This is the most detailed course that I found but not the most practical [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhadeL7_EIU&list=PLzV58Zm8FuBL6OAv1Yu6AwXZrnsFbbR0S

Answer (score 3):

It is called an asterisk.

The asterisk passes all of the items in list into the print function call as separate arguments, without us even needing to know how many arguments are in the list.

You can read more about it here:
https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/